# SCSI to SATA conversion

Tags: scsi

I have Hitachi dk514c-38 drive, which is producing ticking sound. These drives not available anymore. Can I connect a SATA drive instead of this with some converter? 
I also want to know if these is some box or casing available to do this.

Answer (score 0):

To be honest yes, there are sata to scsi adapters available, just look on google. But you have to choose correct adapter for your hardware and I think there should be problems with support of all scsi features.